# Can jQuery ajax be pathched to pass on 404 in Fx?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, qtip2

I am using qtip2 and they seem to use the jQuery ajax.

In IE8 I have no problems. I get the error and the complete

In Fx 6+ I never get the error.

To reproduce:

1. go to http://plungjan.name/eclatooltip/
2. turn on firebug Net or other http sniffer
3. Mouse over the 2nd IPC in the 2nd result - B65D30/08

Result:

- IE: message: "Nothing found"
- Fx: never returns, never executes the error or complete

I have seen this https://gist.github.com/82181

but do not see how to use it in my code.

---

Code used (eclatt.js)

```
    ajax: {
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: url,
      once: false,
      complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { // works perfectly in IE
        // alert("complete:"+jqXHR+":"+ textStatus)
      },
      error: function() { // works perfectly in IE8
        alert('Error')
        this.set('content.text', "Nothing found");
      },
      success: function(oData, sTextStatus, oJqXhr) {
        /* Construct list */

        ... 

        this.set('content.text', sHtml);
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem is, that JSONP calls are handled by appending <script> tag to the  DOM, and network related errors (like 404) doesn't trigger the handlers (at least it shouldn't, I guess the IE is trying to be smarter than it really is).

Quote from the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) error handler description:

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.

To overcome this issue, there are plugins out there like this one [jquery-jsonp](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) that are checking whenever the source of the appended script tag has loaded and are firing appropriate callbacks if not.

**Update**

Here's there source for the ajax plugin for qtip2 https://github.com/Craga89/qTip2/blob/master/src/ajax/ajax.js. You can most probably can replace the

```
// Error handler
function errorHandler(xh, status, error){ api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error); }
// Setup $.ajax option object and process the request
$.ajax( $.extend({ success: successHandler, error: errorHandler, context: api }, opts, { url: url, complete: after }) );
```

With this:

```
if (opts.dataType && opts.dataType.toLowerCase() == 'jsonp') {
    // Error handler
    function jsonpErrorHandler(xOptions, status) {api.set('content.text', 'error: ' + status);}
    // Setup using jsonp
    $.jsonp( $.extend({ success: successHandler, error: jsonpErrorHandler, context: api }, opts, { url: url, complete: after }) );
} else {
    // Error handler
    function errorHandler(xh, status, error){ api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error); }
    // Setup $.ajax option object and process the request
    $.ajax( $.extend({ success: successHandler, error: errorHandler, context: api }, opts, { url: url, complete: after }) );
}
```

It should work provided you have embedded the jquery-jsonp plugin.

Comment: Thanks - do you know how I can replace the qtip ajax call with the one in the link you gave?

Comment: Just changing to $.jsonp worked just now before I saw your more complete solution. Thanks!

Comment: I do get an error `Error: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function
Source File: ...script/qTip2/jquery.qtip.js
Line: 2028, Column: 17
Source Code:
        function jsonpErrorHandler(xOptions, status) `